# How to plot a spiral on a plane?

Tags: plotting

I have a problem where I am given a curve in two dimensions. I must plot this curve on a given plane with the starting point of the curve on a certain point on the plane. I have no problems plotting the plane but I do not understand how to move a curve and tilt it so it lies on the plane.

The curve is defined by `{x[t], y[t]} = {t Cos[2 t], t Sin[2 t]}`. The equation of the plane is `3 (x + 1) + 4 (y - 2) + (z - 2) = 0`. The spiral must be centered at `{-1, 2, 2}`.

Comment: Show the code for what you havre tried. What defines the plane, curve, and point?

Answer (score 7):

Since the given plane is already in a convenient form, we can easily extract the center point and the normal of the plane to use with `RotationTransform[]` and `InfinitePlane[]`. Thus,

```
With[{pt = {-1, 2, 2}, nrm = {3, 4, 1}}, 
     Show[ParametricPlot3D[pt + RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, nrm}][
                           {t Cos[2 t], t Sin[2 t], 0}] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 2 π}], 
     Graphics3D[{{Red, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[pt]},
                 {LightBlue,
                  InfinitePlane[pt, Rest[Orthogonalize[{nrm, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]]]}}], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

[image: spiral in a plane]

Answer (score 5):

The point:

```
p = {-1, 2, 2};
point = ListPointPlot3D[{p}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[Large]}]
```

The plane:

```
eqPlane = 3 (x + 1) + 4 (y - 2) + (z - 2) == 0;

f[x_, y_] := z /. First @ Solve[eqPlane, z]

f[x, y]
```

> 7 - 3 x - 4 y

```
plane = ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

The spiral:

```
{a[t_], b[t_], c[t_]} := {t Cos[2 t], t Sin[2 t], f[a[t], b[t]]}
```

Origin of the spiral:

```
s0 = {a[0], b[0], c[0]}
```

> {0, 0, 7}

Plot of the spiral moved to the point `p`:

```
spiral = ParametricPlot3D[{a[t], b[t], c[t]} - s0 + p, {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Red, BoxRatios -> 1]

Simplify[eqPlane]
```

> 3 x + 4 y + z == 7

```
view = Coefficient[Simplify[First@eqPlane], #] & /@ {x, y, z}
```

> {3, 4, 1}

Result:

```
Show[spiral, plane, point, ViewPoint -> view]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An uninspiring way:

```
{x[t], y[t]} = {t Cos[2 t], t Sin[2 t]};
 p = ({x, y, z} /. First@Solve[(x + 1) + 4 (y - 2) + (z - 2) == 0, z])
q = p /. {x -> x[t], y -> y[t]};
Show[Plot3D[Evaluate[p[[3]]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, Opacity[0.5]}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[q], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]